# How can I model a polyatomic molecule as a system of coupled oscillators?

Tags: classical-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator

(Classical Mechanics)

Let's say I have a polyatomic molecule, what is the best way for finding the equations of oscillations if they are bounded by a torsion spring?

Comment: The point of this kind of model is to give you an intuitive basis for modeling system in a realm (inter-atomic interactions) where you don't have day-to-day experience. You are expected to build up the answer from bits of basic physics. Stuff like Hooke's law.

Comment: What is Your kowledge about such vibrations and IR spectroscopy in general? Why do You imply torsional springs? For coupling of vibrational oscillators or for the vibrations as such?